# how to store user entered value at run time into virtual Text in installjammer?

Tags: jammer

I am using Installjammer .I want user enter username at run time .And that should store in a file.
I have followed below steps:
       after Start Copying Files
       I have added Custom Black Pane2
       then added widget
       I have set following properties of widget-
        Type entry
       X 15
       Y 85
      Virtual Text UNAME
      Text  USERNAME
      I have not set anything into value because I want this will be set when user enter
      value at run time
      after that I have added **Write Text to File**
      I have set the following properties-
       File open Action: Overwrite Existing File
       Files: /home/user/temp.txt
      Text To Write: <%UNAME%>
      Output -It is not writing anything to file temp.text.
      but if I m setting some text in **value** properties of widget then it is writing to
      file.
      Can any one tell me where I am wrong in this ? How to set user entered at run time
      into virtual text ?
      Thanks in Advanced !!